# How to bulk remove certain category from product catalog

Tags: magento2, product, category

I publish content for a merchant, and I want to bulk remove one category from multiple categories assigned to products. I saw there are some answers to help on developer side but not any to solve this as backend user.

Comment: Are you developer or  backend Manager?

Comment: I'm not a developer! I'm working on Magento admin and want to import a csv after removing one category.